# jstree : delete node event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Below is the code I use. The delete_node.jstree is not firing when node is deleted.

```
     $('#tree-container').jstree({
    'plugins' : ['contextmenu'],
    "check_callback" : true,
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            "url" : sTreeUrl + "?operation=gettree",
            "dataType" : "json" ,
            'data' : function (node) {
                  return { 'parent' : node.id, 'tenantid' : tenantid };
                }
        }
    }
    });
    $('#tree-container').on("delete_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        alert("s");
    });
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there - you should put `'check_callback': true` under `core` property as below. Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/aketzedb/)

```
$('#tree-container').jstree({
    'plugins' : ['contextmenu'],    
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : true,
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [their example](https://www.jstree.com/docs/events/), you chain the event delegation before the jstree() instantiation like so:

```
$('#tree-container').on("delete_node.jstree", function (e, data) { // listen for the event
  alert("s");
}).jstree({ //create the instance
    'plugins' : ['contextmenu'],
    "check_callback" : true,
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            "url" : sTreeUrl + "?operation=gettree",
            "dataType" : "json" ,
            'data' : function (node) {
                  return { 'parent' : node.id, 'tenantid' : tenantid };
                }
        }
    }
});
```

I've not tested this and haven't used it myself but it might help. You're example is instantiating jstree before the event is registered which might cause problems depending on how they listen for the events (they could add hooks when creating the instance at which point your version has none).